# How to get selected index value from list box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is a code for my customised DropDownList:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function () {                
       var source = [ "Alappuzha","Eranakulam","Idukki" ];
           // Create a DropDownList
          $("#Widget").jqxDropDownList({autoOpen: true, source: source, selectedIndex: 1, width: '241', height: '30'});
             });
 </script>

  <div id='Widget' >
  </div>
```

How can I get the selected index value from the above list box using javascript?

Comment: i have tried      var b=document.getElementById("Widget");
     if(b[b.selectedIndex].value=="Alappuzha"){
      alert("Thats correct"); 
    }   ......but no use

Comment: Have you tried reading the documentation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the API of jqxDropDownList widget:

```
var selectedIndex = $('#Widget').jqxDropDownList('selectedIndex');
```

Comment: thanx Mr :) then how can i get the selected index value? eg : Alappuzha or Idukki

Comment: you can have it with `source[selectedIndex]`

Comment: @Nik ..sorry i didn't get u :(